# checkboxes in symfony 2 forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a form defined in a controller as below:

```
$addForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('userIds', 'collection', array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'allow_add' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'required' => false
                )
            ))
            ->add('userId', 'hidden')
            ->getForm();
```

In view I am showing a datagrid with bulk delete option. I am using knp paginator for pagination. I am manually rendering fields in the view as below:

```
//Inside loop
 {%for items in pagination %}
<input type="checkbox" name="form[userIds][]" class="ids" value="{{items.id}}"/>
 {%endfor%}
```

I am fetching data in the controller after post request as below:

```
 var_dump($data['userIds']);
```

When the user selects suppose three checkboxes , I get output as below:

```
array (size=4)
0 => boolean true
1 => boolean true
2 => boolean true
3 => boolean true
```

The values should contain userIds like 1,5,6,7 but I am getting boolean values only. What have i done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an [Entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/entity.html): tweak with `expanded` and `multiple` properties, you will get a list of checkboxes that will be bound to your model schema upon submission.

Comment: is it possible to do without entity field type

Comment: I don't know, but why doing things the hard way? ; ))

Comment: I dont want to run the query to fetch all the users.

Comment: And how would you get the users `id`?

Comment: i fetch 10 records (user) per page. when i use entity, it runs the query to fetch all the users. too many queries running makes my page load slow if i have many users

Comment: You can create a custom query via `query_builder` attribute of course  ^^